# Text centered in a circular component

Tags: css, comparative-review, layout, portability

I have surrounded my initials with a circle. This is intended to be a re-usable component in a responsive layout. (When it is re-used the text will always be two letters, and the font won't change. It behaves sensibly when the browser zooms in and out, but I haven't yet considered if a different component size is needed for very small screens.)

[image]

I tried two approaches, firstly with flex layout, and secondly using the box model, and I'm not sure which I prefer.

```css
.flex-profile-icon {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-profile-icon-text {
  align-self: center; /* center on cross-axis, i.e. vertically */
  font-size: 300%;
}

.trad-profile-icon {
  width: 6em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.trad-profile-icon:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%; /* hack for equal height to width */
}
.trad-profile-icon-text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300%;
}

/*
Copyright 2019-2020 by dcorking and Code Boxx
*/
```

```html
<p>
  Aim is for the text to be centered in the circle
</p>

<h2>Flexbox layout</h2>
<div class="flex-profile-icon">
  <a class="flex-profile-icon-text">
    DC
  </a>
</div>

<h2>Traditional box layout</h2>
<div class="trad-profile-icon">
  <div class="trad-profile-icon-text">
    DC
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  Credit for the traditional box layout approach due to <a href="https://code-boxx.com/css-circles-text/#sec-text"><em>How to Create CSS Circles (And Add Text To It)</em>, W.S. Toh of Code Boxx </a> 
</p>
```

I will be interested in your recommendations on maintainability, cross-browser compatibility, and compatibility with layout frameworks such as Foundation (XY Grid or Float Grid) and Bootstrap.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/dcorking/pen/BazWyOj)

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach. It uses [CSS Grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). It requires less code and is easier to maintain.

```css
.circle {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  border: 0.3em solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 6em;
  height: 6em;
}

.initials {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="initials">DC</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome.
Instead of presenting an alternative approach, on this community we are looking to improve existing provided solutions

Comment: Then again, Pi314 offered two measures according to which s/he thinks this alternative preferable.

Comment: You have simplified 4 lines of my layout code to just 2. I particularly like that all the layout code is in the circle class: so clearly easier to maintain.